# Start activity from another package - Issue

Tags: java, android, android-intent, manifest

I downloaded library project from github and imported it into my app project.The problem is that i want to start activity from this library in my main app class.I tried many ways and one of them was:

---

Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
                                          "com.tehedligmail.restorancafeler.RestaurantActivity
                                            ,
                                            "com.cunoraz.pickImages.MainActivity"));"

startActivity(intent);

---

**This is my log:**

**08-29 04:40:13.937: E/AndroidRuntime(11778):**

**android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class**   **{com.tehedligmail.restorancafeler.RestaurantActivity/com.cunoraz.pickImages.MainActivity};**

**have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?**

_---------------------------------------------------------------------------

i tried this but manifest can't show the package and activity class:

```
 <activity android:name="com.luminous.pick.MainActivity">  
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="com.luminous.pick.MainActivity" />  
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  
            </intent-filter>  
        </activity>
```

---

As i understand from log i should define the class that i want to launch in my manifest,but i couldn't write this,even autocomplete of manifest didn't show this class's name.

Thanks in advance.

[For more information This is image shows library and main project of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nXPx.jpg)

Comment: Sorry for my english,i know it is bad. The question just based on the intent action from activity to another one,please don't downvote the question...

Comment: Don't worry about your English, but please do clarify what you've tried, and what isn't working, so that people can help you with your desired result!

Comment: I editted my question :)

Comment: Still not something I know about (I just came across your post in one of the review queues), but seems much more likely that somebody will be able to help now!

Comment: I'm unlucky guy :D

Answer (score 1):

As the [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html#ComponentName(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), I think the package name is problem. Can you try this?

```
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName( "com.cunoraz.pickImages", "com.cunoraz.pickImages.MainActivity"));"
```

And no need to declare this activity in AndroidManifest.xml