# Why does my app crash when launching module activity on some, not all, virtual devices?

Tags: android, module, crash, package, launch

My main app launches fine. I click to launch an imported module package providing messaging function, and it always works on Galaxy Nexus (Android 7.0, API 24) emulator and always fails on Nexus 5X (Android 9, API 28) emulator. In the latter case, the error is:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {com.sendbird.android.sample/com.sendbird.android.sample.main.LoginActivity};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

The library is called by this code:

```
        Intent startLoginActivity = new Intent();
        startLoginActivity.setClassName("com.sendbird.android.sample", "com.sendbird.android.sample.main.LoginActivity");
        startActivity(startLoginActivity);
```

The Manifest in the imported module contains this code:

```
    <activity android:name=".main.LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Imported module launch also fails on connected device Samsung SM-G930V (Android 8.0.0, API 26).

Of course, I want it to work on all of these devices. What could be causing the crashes on some devices but not others?

(The solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45924397/start-activity-from-another-package-issue) produces the same error.)

Here's the project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here's the app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.church.george.vitalconcern"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

}
```

Here's the Sendbird app module build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sendbird.android.sample"
       minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28

        versionCode getVersionCode()
        versionName getVersionName()
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

}


repositories {
    maven { url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smilefam/SendBird-SDK-Android/master/" }
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    // Required for local unit tests (JUnit 4 framework)
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    // SendBird
    implementation 'com.sendbird.sdk:sendbird-android-sdk:3.0.88'

    // Android support libraries
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    // Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'

    // External libraries
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.2'
    implementation 'com.dinuscxj:circleprogressbar:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.stfalcon:multiimageview:0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here's the main app Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    package="com.church.george.vitalconcern">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".VitalConcern"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_vc"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".LognActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
                <activity android:name=".EditListActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name="EditActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".LogoutActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".HelpListActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".HelpActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".AnnounceListActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".AnnounceActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".PostActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
        <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity android:name=".FirstWelcomeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".DetailsActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".PrayerActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".RequestListActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".PrayerListActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".NewEditActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity android:name=".PasswordActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity android:name=".PostConfirmActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".PrivacypolicyActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".TermsofuseActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".DemoWelcomeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
        <activity android:name=".SignupActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity android:name=".StartDemoActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".DemoPrivacyActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".DemoTermsActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".ThankyouActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".ForgotActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".SignupPrivacyActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".SignupTermsActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

Here's the SendBird module Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.sendbird.android.sample">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.stfalcon.multiimageview"/>

    <application
        android:name=".main.BaseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/sendbird_ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".main.LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".main.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/select_channel_type"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".main.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/settings" />
        <activity
            android:name=".main.BlockedMembersListActivity"
            android:label="@string/blocked_members_list" />

        <activity android:name=".utils.PhotoViewerActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".utils.MediaPlayerActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".openchannel.CreateOpenChannelActivity"
            android:label="@string/create_open_channel"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
        <activity
            android:name=".groupchannel.InviteMemberActivity"
            android:label="@string/invite_member" />
        <activity
            android:name=".groupchannel.MemberListActivity"
            android:label="@string/member_list" />
        <activity
            android:name=".groupchannel.MemberInfoActivity"
            android:label="@string/member_info" />
        <activity
            android:name=".groupchannel.CreateGroupChannelActivity"
            android:label="@string/create_group_channel" />
        <activity
            android:name=".openchannel.ParticipantListActivity"
            android:label="@string/participant_list" />
        <activity android:name=".openchannel.OpenChannelActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity android:name=".groupchannel.GroupChannelActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

        <service android:name=".fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".fcm.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you checked if the package names are correct?

Comment: Yes, in the Manifest file: package="com.sendbird.android.sample".

Comment: Inside LoginActivity.java, package="com.sendbird.android.sample.main". This corresponds to the file structure--the file is inside the "main" folder.

Comment: Have you tried initializing the intent in another way? For example with: `Intent startActivityIntent = new Intent(this, com.sendbird.android.sample.main.LoginActivity.class);`

Comment: Yes, tried that. Cannot resolve symbol 'LoginActivity'.  Compilation fails. I also tried      startLoginActivity.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.sendbird.android.sample", "com.sendbird.android.sample.main.LoginActivity"));     I wonder if my problem is a manifest conflict, but I'm not sure how to identify that.

Comment: I am assuming, that you are importing the LoginActivity before starting your app? Also, how did you include your library in to the app? Maybe you included it incorrectly somehow.

Comment: Well, the Sendbird module was imported using Android Studio File->New->Import Module. I corrected the question--it's not really a library; it's an app module. Also, the module integrates nicely on the Galaxy Nexus (Android 7.0, API 24) emulator, but fails on later versions. I wonder if this reflects the introduction of manifest merging in later versions around 2014-15.

Comment: No errors show in Merged Manifest Logs.